# PhpSpreadsheet IReadFilter gives error after update

Tags: php, composer-php, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I have been using PhpSpreadsheet filters for years and now after install on the new machine the function no longer works. Specifically, I created ReadFilter class which implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter.

```
class ReadFilter implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter {

    private $startRow = 0;
    private $endRow = 0;
    private $columns = [];


    public function __construct($startRow, $endRow, $columns) {
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
        $this->endRow = $endRow;
        $this->columns = $columns;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
   
        if ($row >= $this->startRow && $row <= $this->endRow) {
            if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then I want to read data using the filter above:

```
$filterSubset = new ReadFilter(1, 3427, range('A', 'A'));

$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = './file_name.xlsx';
$worksheet='Sheet 1';
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($worksheet)->toArray();
```

However, I get an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of ReadFilter::readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') must be compatible with PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter::readCell(string $columnAddress, int $row, string $worksheetName = ''): bool

Php is not happy with the public function readCell in my ReadFilter class. But the error is not self explanatory. Anybody can help?

Comment: It wants you to add those type declarations to your method. So replace `$column` with `string $column` and so on. Also add `:bool` specifying the return type

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is related to Composer in any way?